# How to find the greatest integer, j, such that j * ( j - 1 ) / 2 < k?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

How to find the greatest integer, j, such that j * ( j - 1 ) / 2 < k ?

Is there a way to find a formula for j in terms of k ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We assume that $k$ is a positive integer. We first find the larger real number $x$ such that $\frac{x(x-1)}{2}=k$.  Solve the quadratic equation. We get 
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+8k}}{2}.$$
For the largest *integer* $j$ such that the desired inequality holds, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ will work unless $x$ is an integer. To get things right, it is better to subtract $1$ and use the ceiling function. So the largest $j$ is
$$\left\lceil \frac{\sqrt{1+8k}-1}{2}\right\rceil.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$j^2 - j < 2k$$

$$j^2 - j + \frac{1}{4} = (j - \frac{1}{2})^2  < 2k + \frac{1}{4}$$

Complete the square. Be careful you include both solutions and flip the less than sign!

$$\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{2k + \frac{1}{4}} < j < \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2k + \frac{1}{4}}$$

Comment: Thanks! (ps, I liked the earlier version that required me to think more...)

Comment: Shouldn't the last part be 2k not just k?

Answer (score 1):

you require
$$
(j-\frac12)^2 \lt 2k+\frac14
$$